# Serilog - Aggregate consecutive identical log message lines

Tags: serilog, serilog-aspnetcore

are you aware of a plugin/filter/sink (or any other sort of code) for Serilog that would aggregate consecutive identical log messages to something like this:

```
[DB] [MyClass] This is a message
[DB] [MyClass] This is a message
[DB] [MyClass] This is a message
Plus 97 more
```

I have some situations where I have a LogDebug inside a Loop, an in some circumstances an identical log line is printed dozens of times, for example in this code

```
//myLargeList as 100 items and all of them raise the same exception
foreach(var item in myLargeList){
  try{
   //do something here with item that throw an Exception
  }catch(Exception e){
    logger.LogDebug("This is a message")
  }
}
```

Is there anything in Serilog that can help me with this?